# XMLHttpRequest Internal Server Error 500 Debugging

Tags: asp.net, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an `api` application which are givin me quite a headache. So in desperation I'm posting my problem here.

***Short version***
In short I need to know how I can debug my application to figure out what is causing the `500 Internal Server Error`, I've tried to look into the Event log, but it doesn't tell me much besides which requests have failed, nothing about why they failed. So I honestly have no clue where to go from here.

The `API` is an `ASP.Net MVC` project and is hosted on an `IIS 8.5` `Windows Server 2012 R2`

Answer (score 1):

try sending a get request and reading the response. To get an increased level of error info, enable remote errors

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684665.aspx

Comment: Just tried that, didn't get any additional information :-(